# Retrive Document Array from FirebaseFirestore --> Java Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve an Object Array that is inside a Document with an ID that I know. I want to then do something with that Array of Objects (In this case they are cards)

[image]

How do I do this? I am using Java with Android Studio

Comment: This article will be for sure very helpful, [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10).

Comment: Reading data is also covered in the Firestore getting started guide [Reading Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the reference to `Rooms` collection is `roomReference` and you have the modal class `Movie` (a basic class which will contain all movie objects coupled with an empty constructor), You can do something like below:

```
roomReference
             .document("IDzA")
             .get()
             .addOnSuccessListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                   DocumentSnapshot movieDocument = task.getResult();
                   if (document.exists()) {
                   List<Map<String, Movie>> movies = (List<Map<String, Movie>>) movieDocument.get("MovieArray");
                   }
                } else
                     Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "No Movies!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
             });
```